# Wordpress theme not displaying ALT tags

Tags: php, wordpress, image, alt

I am trying to add an alt attribute to the image when displayed on the website, but so far with no luck.

Thank you very much and here is the code I'm trying with:

```
<?php $featured = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '1440_1712'); ?>
<?php $alt = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true); ?>
<div class='img-half-wrap' style='background-image: url("<?php echo $featured[0]; ?>");' alt='<?php echo $alt; ?>'>
```

I've tried changing the $post->ID to $featured with no success.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If you test `get_post_meta($post->ID)` without the optional arguments, what results do you see?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I see alt="Array".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `get_post_meta` on wrong object: what you want to get is the `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta from the ***media***, not from the ***post***.

So you should use this:

```
$alt = get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
```